How to connect private PoS networks on different servers?
I created my own private PoS Ethereum testnet using a custom genesis file. I can connect to the first node using RPC and see block generation, and I can make transactions. Now, I want to run a second node and connect it to the first one. However, the execution layer on the second node does not sync with the first node.
Here are the commands I used:
First machine:
Execution Layer:
reth node --datadir=/data/reth/execution-data
--chain=my_network/genesis.json
--http --http.port=8545 --http.addr=0.0.0.0 --http.corsdomain="*" --http.api=admin,net,eth,web3,debug,trace
--ws --ws.addr=0.0.0.0 --ws.port=8546 --ws.api=net,eth --ws.origins="*"
--authrpc.port=8551 --authrpc.jwtsecret=jwtsecret --authrpc.addr=0.0.0.0
--metrics=0.0.0.0:9001 --discovery.port=30303 --port=30303

Beacon Node:
lighthouse beacon_node --datadir=/data/lighthouse/beacon-data
--disable-enr-auto-update --enr-address=0.0.0.0 --enr-udp-port=9000 --enr-tcp-port=9000
--listen-address=0.0.0.0 --port=9000
--http --http-address=0.0.0.0 --http-port=4000 --http-allow-sync-stalled
--slots-per-restore-point=32 --disable-packet-filter
--execution-endpoints=http://0.0.0.0:8551 --jwt-secrets=jwtsecret --suggested-fee-recipient=0x8NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
--metrics --metrics-address=0.0.0.0 --metrics-allow-origin=* --metrics-port=5054
--enable-private-discovery --testnet-dir=my_network

Validator Client:
lighthouse vc --testnet-dir=my_network --validators-dir=my_network/keys
--secrets-dir=my_network/secrets --init-slashing-protection
--beacon-nodes=http://0.0.0.0:4000 --suggested-fee-recipient=0x8NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
--metrics --metrics-address=0.0.0.0 --metrics-allow-origin=* --metrics-port=8080

Second machine:
Execution Layer:
reth node --datadir=/data/reth/execution-data --chain=my_network/genesis.json
--http --http.port=8545 --http.addr=0.0.0.0 --http.corsdomain="*" --http.api=admin,net,eth,web3,debug,trace
--ws --ws.addr=0.0.0.0 --ws.port=8546 --ws.api=net,eth --ws.origins="*"
--authrpc.port=8551 --authrpc.jwtsecret=jwtsecret --authrpc.addr=0.0.0.0
--metrics=0.0.0.0:9001 --discovery.port=30303 --port=30303
--bootnodes=enode://a32f1aa....

Beacon Node:
lighthouse beacon_node --datadir=/data/lighthouse/beacon-data
--disable-enr-auto-update --enr-address=0.0.0.0 --enr-udp-port=9000 --enr-tcp-port=9000
--listen-address=0.0.0.0 --port=9000
--http --http-address=0.0.0.0 --http-port=4000 --http-allow-sync-stalled --slots-per-restore-point=32 --disable-packet-filter
--execution-endpoints=http://0.0.0.0:8551 --jwt-secrets=jwtsecret --suggested-fee-recipient=0x8NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
--metrics --metrics-address=0.0.0.0 --metrics-allow-origin=* --metrics-port=5054
--enable-private-discovery --testnet-dir=my_network
--bootstrap-node=enr:-Iu4QJgrl.....

Validator Client:
lighthouse vc --testnet-dir=my_network/ --validators-dir=my_network/keys
--secrets-dir=my_network/secrets --init-slashing-protection
--beacon-nodes=http://0.0.0.0:4000 --suggested-fee-recipient=0x8NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
--metrics --metrics-address=0.0.0.0 --metrics-allow-origin=* --metrics-port=8080

Using the admin.peers I can confirm that both systems are connected to each other but despite setting up the bootnodes and the ENR settings, the second node's execution layer does not sync from the first node.
Any idea what I might be missing?
